# Firestore security rules for server side code

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

According to what I've read, when a function runs via the server, all Firestore rules are ignored. 
How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Functions use the Admin SDK to access Firestore, which runs with administrative privileges and always bypasses security rules. There is (currently) no way to change this behavior.

Also see:

- [How to use Admin SDK with limited privileges on Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079664/how-to-use-admin-sdk-with-limited-privileges-on-firestore), which shows an interesting workaround.
- [Firebase firstore security rules for cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727411/firebase-firstore-security-rules-for-cloud-functions)
- [How to make Firebase Functions act as a user instead of being an admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176402/how-to-make-firebase-functions-act-as-a-user-instead-of-being-an-admin)